# problems in starting a script in WinDbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am trying to run a WinDebug script but I cannot.
The script I have is preatty simple and called `DBG_SCRIPT.txt` in the same folder where WinDbg is located.
It has the following code that basically starts a debug session.

```
.echo "hi I am starting debugging"
g
```

I tried the following command line but it doesn't start.

```
windbg c:\myapp.exe" -c "$$><$c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\DBG_SCRIPT.txt
windbg c:\myapp.exe" -c "$$><$DBG_SCRIPT.txt
windbg c:\myapp.exe" -c "$$><$.\DBG_SCRIPT.txt
```

is this correct?
I don't see the debugging starting at all.
I have the following error that I also suspect related to pdb symbols used.

```
CommandLine: "c:\myapp.exe" -c "$$><$c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\DBG_SCRIPT.txt"
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line has two problems, the command needs to come before the EXE and you have an extra $. Try this:

windbg -c "$$>< DBG_SCRIPT.txt" c:\myapp.exe

-scott